# YII 2 Framework : Help. It only works on the first page of Gridview

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2, jquery-hover

I made Jquery to show tooltips when mouse hovers on text. It works fine on every pages.

I also have an Image Column in my gridview.
I made Jquery to enlarges those images when mouse hovers on them 
But the problem is, It only works on the first page

I read some articles that suggests to use SELECTOR in JS Script but I don't have any idea how to implement it.

Please Help me.

Thank you so much and I'm sorry to bother you all.

Here is my view Code

```html
<?php
 \yii\web\JqueryAsset::register($this);
 \yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset::register($this);
 $tooltipjs=<<< 'SCRIPT'
 $('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});
SCRIPT;
 $this->registerJs($tooltipjs);

 $jss = <<< 'SCRIPT'
 $(".enlargephoto").hover(function(){
  $(".photobox").remove();
  var srcval = $(this).attr("src");
  var names = $(this).attr("namas");
  $("<div class=\'photobox\' ></div>")
  .html("<p class=\'names\'>"+names+"</p><img src="+srcval+"></img>")
  .appendTo("#usergrids").hide().fadeIn("fast");
 },function(){
  $(".photobox").remove();
 });
 $(".enlargephoto").mousemove(function(e){
  var xx = e.pageX - 20;
  var tt = e.pageY - 120;
  $(".photobox").css({top:tt, left:xx});
 }); 
SCRIPT;
$this->registerJs($jss);

 $css=<<< 'SCRIPT'
  .photobox
  {
   margin-left:200px;
   visibility:visible;
   opacity:1;
   -moz-opacity:1;
   position: absolute ;
   padding:10px;
   border:2px solid Silver;
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(30deg,LightPink,PapayaWhip,NavajoWhite,AliceBlue,AntiqueWhite,Wheat,Khaki,Linen,Ivory,BlanchedAlmond);
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(30deg,LightPink,PapayaWhip,NavajoWhite,AliceBlue,AntiqueWhite,Wheat,Khaki,Linen,Ivory,BlanchedAlmond);
   background:-o-linear-gradient(30deg,LightPink,PapayaWhip,NavajoWhite,AliceBlue,AntiqueWhite,Wheat,Khaki,Linen,Ivory,BlanchedAlmond);
   box-shadow:2px 4px 75px DarkSlateGray;
   -webkit-box-shadow:2px 4px 75px DarkSlateGray;
   -moz-box-shadow:4px 2px 75px DarkSlateGray;
  }
  .photobox img
  {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   border:2px inset Snow;
  }
  .photobox .names p
  {
   line-height:15px;
   font-family: 3Dumb ;
   font-size:25px;
   font-weight:bold;
   text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px DarkSlateGray;
   color:MidnightBlue;
   text-align:center;
   text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  
SCRIPT;
$this->registerCss($css);
?>

<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\BaseUrl;
$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Users List');
?>
<div class="user-record-index">
 <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'userform']); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget(['id'=>'usergrids','options' => ['data-pjax' => true ],
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [

   [
    'label' => 'Foto',
    'format' => 'html',
    'filter'=> '',
    'content' => function($data) 
    {
     $dest = Yii::getAlias('@web/');
     return Html::img($dest . $data->filepath,[
      'class'=>'enlargephoto','width' => '50px','height'=>'50px',
      "style"=>"border:1px ridge Silver; box-shadow:2px 3px 15px Black; 
          -webkit-box-shadow:2px 3px 15px Black;
          cursor:pointer",
      'namas'=>$data->nama,
     ]);
    },
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'content-grid-css'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'header-grid-css'],
    
   ],
   [
    'attribute'=>'username',
    'format'=>'html',
    'content' => function($data) 
    {
     return Html::tag('div', $data->username, 
     [
      'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
      'data-placement'=>'right', 
      'title'=> $data->nama,
      'style'=> 'cursor:pointer;' 
     ]);
    },
    'options' => ['width' => '120'],
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'content-grid-css'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'header-grid-css'],
   ],
   
   [
    'attribute'=>'nama',
    'format'=>'html',
    'content' => function($data) 
    {
     return Html::encode($data->nama);
    },
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'content-grid-css'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'header-grid-css'],
   ],
   
   [
    'attribute'=>'email',
    'format'=>[
     'Email',
    ],
    'value' => function($data)
    {
     return Html::encode($data->email);
    },
    
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'content-grid-css1'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'header-grid-css'],
   ],
   [
                'attribute'=>'create_at',
    'format' =>  ['datetime', 'php:d-m-Y H:i:s'],
    'options' => ['width' => '120'],
    'content' => function($data)
    {
     return Html::encode($data->create_at);
    },
    
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'content-grid-css'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'header-grid-css'],
   ],
   [
    'class' => \yii\grid\ActionColumn::className(),
    //'controller' => 'MarketingController',
    'template' => '{update}{delete}{view}',
    'header' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New',['create','id'=>'addb']),
    'buttons' =>
    [
     'update' => function($url, $model, $key)
     {
      return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', 
      $url,['title'=> Yii::t('app','update'),]);
     }, 
     'delete' => function($url, $model, $key) 
     {
      return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', 
      $url,['title'=> Yii::t('app','delete'),'data-pjax' => 'userform',
      'data-confirm' => Yii::t('app','Are you sure to delete this item'),
      'data-method' => 'post',
      ]);
      
     }
    ],
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'content-grid-css'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'header-grid-css'],
   ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try register Js this way..

```
use yii\web\View;
```

Then your javascript code implement like this...

```
<?php

$this->registerJs("
$('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});

$('.enlargephoto').hover(function(){
        $('.photobox').remove();
        var srcval = $(this).attr('src');
        var names = $(this).attr('namas');
        $('<div class=\'photobox\' ></div>')
        .html('<p class=\'names\'>'+names+'</p><img src='+srcval+'></img>')
        .appendTo('#usergrids').hide().fadeIn('fast');
    },function(){
        $('.photobox').remove();
    });
    $('.enlargephoto').mousemove(function(e){
        var xx = e.pageX - 20;
        var tt = e.pageY - 120;
        $('.photobox').css({top:tt, left:xx});
    }); 
", View::POS_END);
```

You can try also POS_LOAD or POS_READY

Comment: Still only on first page

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an Ajax GridView. In your code the listener to the event "hover" is added only to the element that already exists in the page when its loaded. You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.enlargephoto', function(){
    $('.photobox').remove();
    var srcval = $(this).attr('src');
    var names = $(this).attr('namas');
    $('<div class=\'photobox\' ></div>')
    .html('<p class=\'names\'>'+names+'</p><img src='+srcval+'></img>')
    .appendTo('#usergrids').hide().fadeIn('fast');
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.enlargephoto' ,function(){
    $('.photobox').remove();
});
$('body').on('mousemove', '.enlargephoto' function(e){
    var xx = e.pageX - 20;
    var tt = e.pageY - 120;
    $('.photobox').css({top:tt, left:xx});
});
```

The hover event doesn't exists anymore so I broke it in the real events.